# Creating a string to access a button object

Tags: windows, vb.net

I created a series of buttons on a UI and when I load the UI I added the following lines of code.

```
    AddHandler Button1100.Click, AddressOf FC_ButtonClickFunction
    AddHandler Button1101.Click, AddressOf FC_ButtonClickFunction
    AddHandler Button1102.Click, AddressOf FC_ButtonClickFunction
    AddHandler Button1103.Click, AddressOf FC_ButtonClickFunction
    AddHandler Button1104.Click, AddressOf FC_ButtonClickFunction
    AddHandler Button1105.Click, AddressOf FC_ButtonClickFunction
    AddHandler Button1106.Click, AddressOf FC_ButtonClickFunction
    AddHandler Button1107.Click, AddressOf FC_ButtonClickFunction
    AddHandler Button1108.Click, AddressOf FC_ButtonClickFunction
    AddHandler Button1109.Click, AddressOf FC_ButtonClickFunction
```

This works fine but I would like to use a FOR loop to perform this operation. The Buttons are named Button1100 to Button1109 so I would like to take the base button name "Button1" and append the numbers 100 to 109 to the string and use the newly created string name to perform the AddHandler function.  I'm trying to create a string that will reference an existing button. The code below DOES NOT work but it's an attempt at solving the problem.

```
    Dim s As String
    Dim i As Byte
    For i = 100 To 109
        s = "Button1" + i.ToString
        Dim b As New Button
        b.Name = s
        AddHandler b.Click, AddressOf FC_ButtonClickFunction
    Next
```

I'm using VB.net (2013).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Controls.Find`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find(v=vs.110).aspx) and LINQ:

```
For i = 100 To 109
    dim btnName As String = $"Button1{i}"
    Dim b As Button  = Me.Controls.Find(btnName, False).OfType(Of Button).FirstOrDefault()
    If b IsNot Nothing Then
       AddHandler b.Click, AddressOf FC_ButtonClickFunction
    End If
Next
```

The second parameter in `Find` specifies if you want to search recursively in all child controls. This should not be necessary if you know where they are.

Comment: Thanks Tim. I had to change the Dim b As Button to Dim c() as Control to get the Find to work and from there I was able to get it to work.

Comment: You haven't used FirstOrDefault and OfType. That's why you needed to declare the Control().